# Makefile для модуля ядра Linux с несколькими исходными файлами

Tags: linux, c, makefile, модули, kernel

Всем привет, начал учить программирования ядра Linux. Столкнулся с тем, что не могу правильно собрать модуль. `make` нормально отрабатывает. `insmod` загружает модуль в ядро, но сообщений в логе нет.

**solution.c:**

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include "checker.h"

static const char* msg = "Hello from my module!";
extern void call_me(const char*);

static int __init init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "322\n");
    call_me(msg);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "After the function\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit exitFromModule(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "BYE\n");
    return;
}

module_init(init);
module_exit(exitFromModule);
```

**checker.h:**

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
void call_me(const char* str);
```

**checker.c:**

```c
#include "checker.h"
#include <linux/kernel.h>

void call_me(const char* str)
{
    printk("<1>FROM CALL_ME!\n");
    return;
}
```

**Makefile:**

```make
CURRENT = $(shell uname -r)
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)
DEST = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/misc
TARGET = solution

obj-m := $(TARGET).o
solution-objs  :=  checker.o

all:
        make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD)  modules

clean:
        make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
        @rm -f *.o .*.cmd .*.flags *.mod.c *.order;
        @rm -f .*.*.cmd *.symvers *~ *.*~ TODO.*
        @rm -fR .tmp*
        @rm -rf .tmp_versions
```

[image: Make's result:]

[image: Inserting and dmesg:]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127160/discussion-on-question-by-welcometomytutorial-makefile----linux--).

Comment: 1) Во все операторы *printk()* добавьте в начало приметную строку, типа "+++" или в таком духе 2) tail -f /var/log/messages | grep '+++' & 3) insmod solution.ko